# Excel dates to Python and back to excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, date, time

I am working with python and extracting data from it. I have created a 2d array of the excel table and I am trying to find the index of a certain date. However, when I print one of the dates out from my 2d array, it prints out `<PyTime: 7/9/2014 12:00:00 AM>` while in excel it is `07/09/14`. It also prints out of type time when I check the type. Suppose my array is named `2darray`.

I am trying to use `2darray.index(object)` but I do not know what to insert into the parameter. Can someone help with this problem? I am beginner at using python to extract data from excel, and your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "it prints out while in excel it is 07/09/14" mean? Please show us what code you're using so we can see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your date that prints `<PyTime: 7/9/2014 12:00:00 AM>` is stored under the variable `my_date`. You can do the following to transform it into a native Python datetime object:

```
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime(month=my_date.month, day=my_date.day, year=my_date.year,
            hour=my_date.hour, minute=my_date.minute, second=my_date.second)
```

You might benefit though from using my library [xlwings](http://xlwings.org) where you can do:

```
from xlwings import Range, Workbook
wb = Workbook(r'path\to\your\workbook.xlsx')
my_date = Range('A1').value  # prints: datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 7, 12, 0)
```

That is, it automatically gives you a native Python `datetime` object that offers you all the desired methods to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this action with win32com. You need to clean the date format in your python list, for example:

```
Import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wbxl = xl.Workbooks.Open('D:/myworkbooks.xlsx')
xlsheet = wbxl.ActiveSheet

mydatelist = []
for row in range(0,50]:
    mydatelist.append(str(xlsheet.Cells(row,1).Value))
    mydatelist = [word.replace('12:00:00 AM','') for word in mydatelist]
```

and you can do this after:

```
import time
date = []
for x in mydatelist :
date.append(time.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d '))
```